# Getting current selection in objective c using WebKit framework?

Tags: objective-c, macos, webkit

Is there any method available in WebKit framework which tells that user has clicked on a particular button of the the web page or user clicked on some link.I want to perform some action when user clicks on a button of a  webpage,but i am not able to identify that that user clicked on a button.I searched a lot but i am not able to find such method.Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the UI delegate and the policy delegate via `[webView setUIDelegate:]` and `[webView setPolicyDelegate:]`, and implement the delegate methods explained in [Web UI delegate protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001915) and in [Web Policy delegate protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebPolicyDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001912).

Look for `webView:mouseDidMoveOverElement:modifierFlags:` in the UI delegate and `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:` in the policy delegate to achieve what you want to do.